# ld: library not found for -liPhone-lib

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, ios-simulator, xcode4.3

I installed Xcode 4.3.3 and iOS simulator 5.1, After that i am getting this linker error

```
ld: library not found for -liPhone-lib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see   invocation)
```

Please guide me to fix this.

Note: I didn't delete Xcode 4.2 version and my build is working fine in this version.

Comment: can just give us some more info on what you're trying to do? E.g. what are you building? Which libraries, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

make  Pod ->Build Settings ->Build Active Architecture Only  is NO not Yes

Comment: So... don't ship the app with all necessary CPU architectures?  Apple will reject the app -> back to square one.